# GTK3 TreeView column headers missing

Tags: server, gnome, python, gtk

[image: gedit missing column headers]

The above shows the expected "Name", "Size", and "Accessed" column headers distinctly missing from GEdit's File->Open dialog. Here's some detail:

We've got a freshly developed, Python 3/PyGObject GUI application which runs fine on my desktop (Arch Linux, running Gnome) and three coworkers' (Ubuntu 18.04 for two, ElementaryOS for the third). It also works whether I'm running Plasma or XFCE.

Our servers, however, are running Ubuntu 18.04.2 and run VNC instances of Fluxbox. When we run the Python app on those, or even a strictly minimal C example of a GTK TreeView, the column headers vanish. They are still present both in terms of widget size and functionality (you can sort by size in GEdit, for example) but are invisible in terms of label or borders. No color changes/font changes seem to have effect on visibility, but adding a tooltip works as with sorting.

The current theory is that having a full Gnome desktop installed has some effect on configuration or code accessed by Python that is not present when Ubuntu Server is installed, along with libgnome-3-dev and other supporting libraries. The two Ubuntu Desktop installs have the same package versions installed for all of the supporting libraries, yet the behavior differs in this one way.

A passable workaround (though not yet tested) would be to run Ubuntu Desktop on our servers and just disable the login manager service. However, that seems like an inadequate bandage, to say the least. I'd very much like to know what exactly is breaking the GTK library and fix that.

Any pointers to this end or other scenarios to test would be appreciated.